# What step would u take to refactor a ball of mud CF app into something modern and maintainable

Tags: coldfusion, legacy

I am going to pick up a task that no one has ever attempted to try at my workplace.  It is a CF app first written using CF 2.0 (Yes, 2.0!) 10 yrs ago with > 10 cfscheduler tasks..  We explored the idea of rewriting the app, but 10 yrs of work simply can't be rewrote in 2-3 months.

What steps shall one take to modernize the app into a maintainable, extendable state?  The one that I keep hearing is "write tests", but how can I write tests when it wasn't even in MVC?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

p.s. I should thank Allaire, Macromedia and Adobe for keeping CF so freaking backward compatible all the way back to 2.0!

btw, what's the most modern, maintainable state for a CF app without MVC framework?  or should my end goal be ultimately refactoring it into a MVC app?? I can't image how many links I will break if I do... seems impossible... thought?

update: found 2 related Q's...

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/how-do-you-dive-into-large-code-bases
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29788/how-do-you-dive-into-a-big-ball-of-mud

Comment: +1. Good timing. July must be re-factoring month ;)

Comment: Just July? I wish... this will take me months or years...

Comment: Believe me .. I sympathize. Mine will take months too. I am thinking smaller changes (organizing, structure changes like others suggested) is best.

Comment: Start with the data - is the data / database changing?

Comment: I guess the DB layer is less of two evils.  The CFML codes needs a much needed update to CF9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you need to move the whole site to a MVC application.  Recently I did helped with an site that was not MVC, that still had a library with the Models, Services and Assemblers in a clean and organized manor.  It worked great, and we didn't need to do anything more than what was necessary.

That being said, my first step would be to organize the spaghetti code into their different purposes.  It may be hard to properly create the models, but at the very least you could break out the services like functions from the pages.  With that done, it should be a lot cleaner already.

Then, I would try to take the repeated code and put them into custom tags.  It will make the code more reusable, and easier to read.

Good Luck!

Comment: so... the goal is.. to make it more readable and intro some structure if it lacks?  Good advice, thx!

Comment: Yup, there is no reason to make something more complicated than it needs to be. Especially when there is a time limit

Answer (score 3):

Consider, whether a full fledged framework is really necessary. In its most basic form a framework is merely highly organized code. So if procedural, that is well organized, works leave it.

Keep in mind something like FW/1 as migration path can be better than say Coldbox if you don't need all the other stuff.

Lastly, consider this I was able to migrate a 4.5 almost 70% of the way to Coldbox (very simple and really more about directory and file organization versus IOC, plugins, modules, etc...) just using a few extra lines per file plus onMissingMethod functions.

Good Luck.

Comment: onMissingMethod? How does that help?

Comment: Henry went and looked at my code. So in Coldbox Luis has the onMissingAction which not exactly missingmethod works fairly similar.
So I had this

Comment: what do you handle in the onMissingAction?  To capture pages that you may have missed?

Answer (score 3):

I had to deal with a similar situation for about two years at my last job, however, it wasn't quite as old as yours.  I think I was dealing with code from 4.0 on.  There's no silver bullet here, and you'll need to be careful that you don't get too caught up in re-factoring the code and costing your company tons of money in the process.  If the app works as it is rewriting it would be a pretty big wast of money.

What I did was update small chunks at a time, I wouldn't even refactor whole templates at a time, just small portions of one at a time. If I saw a particular ugly loop, or nested if statements I'd try to clean it up the best I could.  If the app can be broken down into smaller modules or areas of functionality and you have the extra time you can try to clean up the code a module at a time.

A good practice I heard from the Hearding Code podcast is create a testing harness template that would use a particular cfm page that has a known output that you can re-run to make sure that it still has the same output once you've done refactoring. Its not nearly as granular as a unit test, but its something and something is almost always better than nothing, right?

Comment: testing harness template...?  Most templates I think will be reading from DB and manipulate / display the result.  How would you write a harness template for that? thx

Comment: Assuming that you have a sandbox to point your database to, you would create a new cfm file that does an include of the original file.  You'd then set whichever vars are required by the template in the new cfm page and after the include you can dump whatever information you'd like to use for verification.  This way when you refactor the underlying template you can run the test page to make sure that you still get the expected output, you could also use the template to wrap the entire call in a transaction (if the legacy code doesn't use them) and rollback.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the reason this app hasn't been touched for years is because for the most part it works. So the old adage "if it ain't broken don't fix it" probably applies; However, code can always be improved :)

The first thing I'd do is switch to Application.cfc and add some good error logging. That way you may find out about things that need to be fixed, and also if you do make changes you're know if they break anything else.

The next thing I'd do is before you change any code is use selenium to create some tests - it can be used as a FireFox plugin and will record what you do. It's really good for testing legacy apps without much work on your part.

Chances are that you won't have much if any protection from SQL injection attacks so you will want to add cfqueryparam to everything!!

After that I'd be looking for duplicated code - eliminating duplicate code is going to make maintenance easier.

Good luck!

Comment: selenium... I'll keep that in mind.  It's like a macro recording thing that helps you click, type, and verify state of DOM, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, I'm currently involved in converting an old CF app into an MVC3 application.
Now this isn't CF2, it was updated as recently as a year ago so all of this may not apply at all to your scenario, apologies if this is the case.

The main thing I had to do consolidate the mixed up CFQuerys and their calls into logical units of code that I could then start porting in functionality either to C# or JavaScript.

Thankfully this was a very simple application, the majority of the logic was called on a database using the DWR Ajax library; that which wasn't was mostly consolidated in a functions.cfm file.

Obviously a lot of that behavior doesn't need to be replicated as packaging up the separate components of logic (such as they were) in the CF app did map quite neatly to the various Partial Views and Editor Templates that I envisaged in the MVC application.

After that, it was simply a case of, page by page, finding out which logic was called when, what it relied upon that then finally creating a series of UML class and sequence diagrams.

Honestly though, I think I gained the most ground when I simply hit File-New Project and started trying to replicate the behavior of the app from the top of index.cfm.

Comment: I didn't say it was fun :D  My workplace has decided to go from CF to .Net/SQL/Oracle across the board so there's a lot of this work to do at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I would break logical parts of the app into CFC's

Pick a single view, look at the logic within. Move that out to a CFC and invoke it.

Keep doing that you will have something much easier to work with that can be plugged into an MVC later. Its almost no work to do this, just copy and paste sections of code and call them.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using object factory to layer your application. We have similar situation at work and we started refactoring by putting Lightwire DI framework.

First we migrated all the sql statement into gateways, then we started using services and take a lot of code out of the templates to the services.

The work is not finished yet but the application is looking better already.

Comment: object factory? and.. how does lightwire DI help?

Comment: As others have suggested here, refactoring out the sql is a good first step (and will often remove a lot of duplicate sql statements). In our app we moved our sql to gateways. We introduced services to provide access to our gateways as well as a place to consolidate a lot of our business logic (also removing duplicate code here). We used Lightwire as our object factory to wire the services and gateways together.

Comment: oh i see, how's lightwire?  I've never used it.  Used to use ColdSpring and now using Wirebox in ColdBox.

Answer (score 0):

For large, really complex applications I'd prefer ColdBox for a re-factor project. However, I just saw a presentation at the D2W Conference on [F/W 1 (Framework One)](http://fw1.riaforge.org/), a VERY simple ColdFusion MVC framework. [Check out code from the presentation here](https://github.com/cybersonic/fw1_demo).

It's 1 (one) CFC file and a set of conventions for organizing your code. I highly recommend evaluating it for your project.

Comment: Thx, I've already used it for another project.  I'd say, yes it satisfies most simple CF app.  The thing is, from non-MVC to MVC, doesn't seems worth it.